# Webkit animation stop and reverse

Tags: css, animation, webkit, css-animations

I'm having a little trouble with Webkit animations. I want the animation to play one way when a user rolls over, and the other way when they roll out. Simple no? Apparently not for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/hornerlas/xFhkm/16/ - Here is the fiddle.

Obviously I did a bit of digging and found the little minx they call fill-mode. weirdly -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; isn't working for me. I know there are a few questions already out there about this, but i wouldn't post it if i found a good one.

I'd rather not tackle this in JS but it seems like the obvious workaround at this point.

Thanks everybody, if you'd rather just see the code... here it is.

CSS

```
 .hi {
      width: 171px;
      height: 171px;
      background-image: url([URL]);

      -webkit-animation: play .3s steps(6) 1;
      -moz-animation: play .3s steps(6) 1;
      -ms-animation: play .3s steps(6) 1;
      -o-animation: play .3s steps(6) 1;
      animation: play .3s steps(6) 1;
  }

  .hi:hover
  {
     -webkit-animation-play-state:running;
     -webkit-animation-direction: reverse; 
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes play {
     from { background-position:    0px; }
       to { background-position: -1026px; }
  }

  @-moz-keyframes play {
     from { background-position:    0px; }
       to { background-position: -1026px; }
  }

  @-ms-keyframes play {
     from { background-position:    0px; }
       to { background-position: -1026px; }
  }

  @-o-keyframes play {
     from { background-position:    0px; }
       to { background-position: -1026px; }
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="hi"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect but it worked

```
    .hi {
    width: 171px;
    height: 171px;
    background-image: url("http://www.samhorner.co.uk/images/locqicomingsoon.png");

    -webkit-animation: play 3s;/* i think you have some wrong in its value */
       -moz-animation: play 3s;
        -ms-animation: play 3s;
         -o-animation: play 3s;
            animation: play 3s;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
   -webkit-animation-play-state:paused;/* pause when initialize */
}

.hi:hover
{
   -webkit-animation-play-state:running;
   -webkit-animation-direction: reverse; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -1026px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@-ms-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@-o-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}
```

Syntax

```
animation: name duration timing-function delay iteration-count direction;
```

Read more here [Animation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp)

Comment: For me this just scrolled through the images like a carousel which isn't the effect i'm trying to get. It should look like an animated sequence, hence the steps(6) function. Thanks for taking a look though.

Comment: Closer, but it needs to play once forwards, and then play backwards once when the user rolls out. Just like a simple rollover state on a button.

Answer (score 0):

So after doing a bit of searching, we found there is actually a little bug that stops fill-mode working with background-position. This stops it working completely. You can test this with my jsfiddle by just adding a transition rather than the background-position. Hopefully it gets fixed soon.

**In short...**

- There is a bug stopping this from happened due to background
  position.
- Use Javascript if you need this effect to work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this evening I was working a somewhat similar issue in wanting to have one of those 3D circular carousels that would rotate one way when :hover was over one thing and in the other direction when :hover over another.

After going round after round with the beasty, pouring over w3c specs and the like I came to understand why it was not going to work exactly that way, but along the way to solving that little CSS puzzle I may have hit upon a thought for your situation.

something:hover #themovingthing {}
something:not(:hover) #themovingthing {}

I would do a sample but I got a ton more to do in the next 72 hours, but as I had read this question along the way I thought I'd toss the basic clue out there.

BTW in the rotating carousel bit ,I ended up using an extra DIV for the other direction of rotation to stay pure CSS because for whatever reason the logical approach to this problem won't play nice in the same overlapping selector contexts that everyone including myself seems to  shoot for.